# Using IF statements to find string length in array for alignment (Visual Basic)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, if-statement, alignment, string-length

My question is just as it says in the title. How would one use IF statements to find the string-length of content in an array, and then make it so that they show up in a Rich Text Box with the left sides aligned?

Noting that one value in my array is a Decimal.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Convert

Public Class frmAll
    'Declare Streamreader
    Private objReader As StreamReader

    'Declare arrays to hold the information
    Private strNumber(24) As String
    Private strName(24) As String
    Private strSize(24) As String
    Private decCost(24) As Integer

    Private Sub frmAll_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object,
                            ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Set objReader
        objReader = New StreamReader("products.csv")
        'Call the FillArray sub to fill the array
        Call FillArray()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillArray()
        'Declare variables and arrays
        Dim decCost(24, 1) As Decimal
        Dim strFields() As String
        Dim strRec As String
        Dim intCount As Integer = 0
        Dim chrdelim As Char = ToChar(",")
        'Set strRec to read the lines
        strRec = objReader.ReadLine

        'Do while loop to fill array.
        Do While strRec <> Nothing
            strFields = strRec.Split(chrdelim)
            strNumber(intCount) = strFields(0)
            strName(intCount) = strFields(1)
            strSize(intCount) = strFields(2)
            decCost(intCount, 0) = ToDecimal(strFields(3))
            decCost(intCount, 1) = ToDecimal(strFields(4))
            'Set strRec to read the lines again
            strRec = objReader.ReadLine
            'increment the index
            intCount += 1
        Loop
        'Call the Calculate sub for calculation
        Call Calculate(decCost)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Calculate(ByVal numIn(,) As Decimal)
        'Define arrays to hold total cost
        Dim decRowTotal(24) As Decimal

        'Define variables to hold the counters for rows and columns
        Dim intR As Integer
        Dim intC As Integer

        'Calcualte total cost
        For intC = 0 To 1
            For intR = 0 To 24
                decRowTotal(intR) += numIn(intR, intC) * 1
            Next
        Next
        'Call the Output sub to configure the output.
        Call Output(numIn, decRowTotal)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Output(ByVal NumIn(,) As Decimal, _
                       ByVal RowTotalIn() As Decimal)
        'Variables
        Dim strOut As String

        Dim intR As Integer = 0
        Dim intC As Integer = 0
        'Set header for output.
        strOut = "ID" & vbTab & "Item" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Size" & _
            vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Total Price" & _
            vbCrLf & "---------- ... -------------------------" & vbCrLf

        'For loop to add each line to strOut, setting
        'the RowTotalIn to currency.
        For intC = 0 To 24
            strOut &= strNumber(intC) & vbTab
            strOut &= strName(intC) & vbTab
            strOut &= strSize(intC) & vbTab
            strOut &= RowTotalIn(intC).ToString("c") & vbCrLf
        Next
        'Add strOut to rbtAll
        rtbAll.Text = strOut
    End Sub
End Class
```

Output:

> P0001  Coffee - Colombian Supreme 24/Case: Pre-Ground 1.75 Oz
>   Bags  $16.50
>
> P0002 Coffee - Hazelnut   24/Case: Pre-Ground 1.75 Oz Bags    $24.00
>
> P0003 Coffee - Mild Blend 24/Case: Pre-Ground 1.75 Oz Bags    $20.50
>
> P0004 Coffee - Assorted Flavors   18/Case. Pre-Ground 1.75 Oz
>   Bags  $23.50
>
> P0005 Coffee - Decaf  24/Case: Pre-Ground 1.75 Oz Bags    $20.50

It shows up with vbTabs in my output, but still, it looks similar in that they are not aligned. The first two do, but after that they are not, and I am totally lost.

Comment: You need to provide some code. It would be nice to see what you've done so far to solve this, but at the very least it would be good for you to show the input (with declarative code) and your desired output. Many of us use tools like LINQPad to test our answers before we post them. If you can give us the input code it makes our job much easier.

Comment: Added my code. I need to make it so the left side alignment is, well, aligned in each column. My professor said this was possible using IF statements to fight the length and then, I guess, add vbTabs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, unless you're using a fixed width font, the string length isn't really relevant.  And if you are, what you want to do is use String.PadLeft, not the length of the string.

Comment: I would, but if I made a loop to add the padding still may not help because the parts of the array are not aligned already. Some are lined up with the header, some are to the left, others to the right.

Answer (score 1):

In order to measure the length of a text in pixels, you can write

```
pixels = System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(text, font)
```

The `MeasureText` method has many overloads with arguments that influence the measurement. The problem is, that you cannot really know how the `RichTextBox` renders and calculates text lengths. However, this method will yield more precise results than just counting the number of characters in a text when using a proportional font. See this example, both lines are ten characters long:

> iiiiiiiiii
>   mmmmmmmmmm

---

**UPDATE**

A note on using tabs to format the text. Example with two columns where the second column starts at the 5th tab position.

```
Column #1                               Column #2

------>|------>|------>|------>|------>|Some text
Short->|------>|------>|------>|------>|Some more text
A bit longer-->|------>|------>|------>|Even more text
An even longer text--->|------>|------>|The last one
```

As you can see, depending on the length of the text in the first column, you have to add a different number of tabs before the second column. On the first line the first column is empty and on the second line there is a text which is shorter than the tab width. In both cases you need to insert 5 tabs. On the 3rd and 4th lines the texts are longer and you need to insert only 4 and 3 tabs respectively.

This gives you an idea on how the correct number of tabs can be calculated.